# Adding "show all" to a drop down list in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have created a GridView in Visual Studio 2010.
The information displayed in the GridView is controlled by a dropdown list.
Can I add a "Show all" option to the dropdown list so that the GridView shows all the data?

This is what I have so far...

Dropdown list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="dorpDownList2" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="Type" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
    AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Select a type"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

GridView code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" emptydatatext="No data was found.">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OrgName" HeaderText="Organisation" 
                SortExpression="OrgName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectTitle" HeaderText="Project title" 
                SortExpression="ProjectTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" 
                SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" 
                HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" 
                DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="OrgName" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="orgDetails.aspx?OrgName={0}" 
                HeaderText="Details" Text="Organisation details" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

SqlDataSource1

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [OrgName], [ProjectTitle], [Type], [Amount] FROM [tabRequest] WHERE [Type] = @Type">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I can obviously add "Show all" to the drop down list using asp:ListItem but how do I add the functionality to make that actually show all the results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: post your SqlDataSource1 code

Comment: You modify your datasource to accept a control parameter (the DDL) and modify the sql to show all the data when the DDL `SelectedValue` is 0

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta I have added SqlDataSource1 to my question.

Comment: Are you trying to modify how the Grid acts inside the designer in visual studio or are you trying to modify the behavior when you are running a program using the GridView? EDIT: Also, why are you using Visual Studio 2010? You can get 2013 Community edition for free (2015 too once it is released) from [the visual studio website](https://www.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the drop down list and grid run in a web form. It all works fine but I want to add an item to the drop down list that says "Show all" when a user selects that, the grid should show all the results.

I know there are newer versions of VS. I am stuck with 2010 for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @fnostro yes, that is the question. How would I actually do that though?

Comment: I'll provide an explanation in an answer - this will be too lengthy

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is via the Configure Data Source context menu.  You already have a parameter, as you move through the configuration process you come to a dialog called Define Parameters.  You should see "Type" listed in the Parameters list.  Select it and change the Parameter source to "Control" and when prompted specify the DDL.

The trick is that you need to effectively remove the condition on your select where clause when `Type` is 0.  This is easily done with an IF statement.